# How to make a Python script run without it opening the console window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to double click on my Python script (which uses a Tkinter GUI) and I just want it to open the Tkinter window, not the console window.

To do this, I changed the extension from .py to .pyw and this seems to work fine on Windows but when I double click my .pyw file on a Linux machine, it doesn't work. It simply froze and I had to restart my system.

Please suggest a platform-independent solution that would help me to run the Python script without opening the terminal/command prompt.

Comment: The reason this works on Windows is that it runs a different executable, called `pythonw.exe`. I don't know what the equivalent is on Linux I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pyinstaller` to create the executables for the different platforms you want.

For example,

The syntax of the pyinstaller command is:

```
pyinstaller [options] script [script ...] | specfile
```

In the most simple case, set the current directory to the location of your program myscript.py and execute:

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

PyInstaller analyzes myscript.py and:

```
Writes myscript.spec in the same folder as the script.
Creates a folder build in the same folder as the script if it does not exist.
Writes some log files and working files in the build folder.
Creates a folder dist in the same folder as the script if it does not exist.
Writes the myscript executable folder in the dist folder.
```

In the dist folder you find the bundled app you distribute to your users.

Normally you name one script on the command line. If you name more, all are analyzed and included in the output. However, the first script named supplies the name for the spec file and for the executable folder or file. Its code is the first to execute at run-time.

For certain uses you may edit the contents of myscript.spec (described under Using Spec Files). After you do this, you name the spec file to PyInstaller instead of the script:

```
pyinstaller myscript.spec
```

You may give a path to the script or spec file, for example

```
pyinstaller options... ~/myproject/source/myscript.py
```

or, on Windows,

```
pyinstaller "C:\Documents and Settings\project\myscript.spec"
```

[pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki)

Answer (score 3):

it's been a while since i tried on linux, but i believe it should be fairly simple, firstly you need to put a shebang at the top of the script so your shell knows which executable to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or if you want a specific version you can expand this to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
```

using whichever version you want (only works for first 2 digits)

then you need to mark it as executable:

```
chmod 711 myfile.py
```

for more info on this see this [page](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm)

then when you double click it, on the rpi (last i used linux) it asks if you want to execute it, or execute it in the terminal.

if you choose to execute it without the terminal, you should only see the tkinter GUI