# running .exe extentioned python program without appearing dos screen on PC that doesn't have python executer

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I wrote a program and ı am going to send it to a friend. He doesn't have python console or executor on his pc so ı converted the program to exe using cxfreeze. Program runs without any problem but when it runs a DOS window appears. So ı don't want it to pop-up like that.I want it to run without any window appearing.There is some questions asked on this site  about this problem but all the answer are for PC that has Python console or executor. But ı want it to run on a computer that doesn't have python without appearing any windows. So What can I do to overcome this problem;?

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271861/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-without-it-opening-the-console-window).

Comment: My question is not asked before. As I wrote before all the aswers that are given is for pcs that has python executer . But I want it to run on a pc that doesn't has any python executer or any python console. If the computer doesnt have pythonw.exe it can't execute the program by using pythonw.exe. Please don't give me same answer that are given before

Comment: The current marked duplicate says that you need to run it with pythonw.exe. Search for that with cx_freeze and you'll find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523867/hide-console-window-with-tkinter-and-cx-freeze).

Comment: Or perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880316/how-can-i-hide-the-console-window-when-freezing-wxpython-applications-with-cxfre).

Comment: On Windows, at least, It might have been easier to have your friend install python.  And then it would have been available to run multiple scripts.

Comment: Thanks to TigerhawkT3 I found the answer.